# I am having troubles with looping in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I have the following code. whenever i change the value in the array - `data[0]` to say `data[1]` the value changes. i have about 4 items stored in the `data` array.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: "http://<mywebsite>/user/id/1",
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function() {
        alert("Success");
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Failed!');
    },
  }).then(function(data) {
    var result = data [1];
    console.log(result);
    $('.ch-name').append(result.ch_name);
    $('.ch-logo').append(result.ch_logo);
    $('.ch-desc').append(result.ch_desc);
    $('.ch-genre').append(result.ch_genre);
  });
```

});

I want to display all the data in the array. how do i do that? I have tried doing it this way but it didnt work . i have tried other ways too , but still.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: "http://<mywebsite>/user/id/1",
        type: 'GET',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function() {
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Failed!');
        },
    }).then(function(data) {
        var result = data [1];
        console.log(result);

    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        $('.ch-name').append(result[i].ch_name);
        $('.ch-logo').append(result[i].ch_logo);
        $('.ch-desc').append(result[i].ch_desc);
        $('.ch-genre').append(result[i].ch_genre);
    }    
  });
});
```

Comment: What format is this `data` you receive in?

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean?

Comment: What does your `console.log(result);` looks like?

Comment: It depends on the content of result array, can you post the console.log output?

Comment: @Huey it's an array. the data type is json.

Comment: @CerealKiller [object object] . PhilVarg solved it for me . however , i am facing another problem with it  so i posted more detail below .thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the description is a little unclear but i think i see what youre trying to do.

it should be accomplished by changing that `for` loop to loop over data, not results

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $('.ch-name').append(data[i].ch_name);
    $('.ch-logo').append(data[i].ch_logo);
    $('.ch-desc').append(data[i].ch_desc);
    $('.ch-genre').append(data[i].ch_genre);
}
```

if this is not what youre trying to do, please post what the structure of data looks like, and how you want to display that

Comment: hi , thanks for your time . your script helped grab everything from the array and displayed it . But there was a little bit of problem  , and am not sure if its the for loop or a css bug. This is how i styled the first data in the array (look at the channel area)  [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wlg0zneaydhlnqe/Screenshot_2015-07-01-16-06-45.png?dl=0) .  So i was thinking if i should grab the rest of the data , they will appear below it uniformly. but no , everything was mixed; this is how it looked  - [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f5x51jyku2ypsu6/Screenshot_2015-07-01-15-51-22.png?dl=0)

Comment: url to the data is [link](http://engridmedia.com/next/api/channel/user/id/1) . thank you.

Comment: You are doing a loop, appending the data everytime to same element; so the second link you posted is the normal behaviour (the ".ch-name" element will contain the concatenation of all names, and so on); I think you should have a container div for the 4 ch elements, and clone it in every cycle

Comment: @CerealKiller thank you. i applied what you just thought me. for just 4 elements it doesnt seem like a problem . Would be a pain to do if its about 100 elements. thanks

Comment: There are many ways to handle this, I've made a little example as a starting point: https://jsbin.com/gudacikusu/1/edit?css,js,output